# JavaLite examples, Simple Example Running Error

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

Every time i run Simple-example downloaded from github JavaLite examples, I get this error. Exception in thread "main" org.javalite.activejdbc.InitException: Failed to connect to JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql:mysql://localhost/movies with user: root. Also in read me file there is said to run mvn db-migrator:create command but I also get an error. Why is that, I have downloaded maven and my mvn process-classes builed successfully. Also I am interested in more JavaLite material, there are so few on the internet.

Comment: If there is some tutorial of have to integrate JavaLite on Eclipse (except the one on the JavaLite.io page) it would be helpfull.

Comment: Specifically, which example are you trying?

Comment: Also, you can configure Eclipse using these instructions: https://javalite.io/eclipseIntegration

Comment: it also says that the error is  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:mysql://localhost/Movies.

Comment: Simple-example. Can you give me a more detailed info on how to run this example.

Comment: javalite.io/eclipseIntegration  i and it works fine the instrumentation

Answer (score 0):

There is a README.md file in this example project:
https://github.com/javalite/javalite-examples/blob/master/simple-example/README.md

It has exact instructions to run this example. One of the steps is:

- Adjust your database connection parameters in file:

```
src/main/resources/database.properties
```

This will ensure  you have a correct configuration for your database.

Comment: @ivan-slavić, if this answer helped, you can upvote it